# Open file from notification

Tags: android, file, android-intent

I download a file from a server. For this action I'm showing a notification with indeterminate progress. When the file will be downloaded I want to open it with a click on the notification.

I get the extension and try to open it with `intent` like this

```
public static Intent openFile(Context context, File file) {
    String fileName = file.getName();

    String extension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);


    String type = "application/" + extension;

    if (getAttachmentType(fileName) == AttachmentType.IMAGE) {
        type = "image/*";
    } else if (getAttachmentType(fileName) == AttachmentType.AUDIO) {
        type = "audio/*";
    } else if (getAttachmentType(fileName) == AttachmentType.VIDEO) {
        type = "video/*";
    } else if (getAttachmentType(fileName) == AttachmentType.WORD) {
        type = "application/msword";
    } else if (getAttachmentType(fileName) == AttachmentType.EXCEL) {
        type = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    } else if (getAttachmentType(fileName) == AttachmentType.POWERPOINT) {
        type = "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint";
    } else if (getAttachmentType(fileName) == AttachmentType.TXT) {
        type = "text/*";
    }

    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, context.getResources().getString(R.string.open_file_with));
    intent.setDataAndType(path, type);
    return chooser;
}
```

And on the notification do this

```
Intent intent = ActionsHelper.openFile(context, file);
if (intent != null) {
     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
      mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
}
```

My problem is that with any extension the message on the chooser is **No app can perform this action**. Am I missing something?

Comment: Where is `getAttachmentType` and `AttachmentType.CONSTANTS`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I found it. I replace

`PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);`

with

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

and it worked

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the Intent data and type *after* creating the chooser Intent.  Switch it to:

```
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.setDataAndType(path, type);

Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, context.getResources().getString(R.string.open_file_with));
```

Comment: @vasilis I'm not sure the `application/` type prefix is necessary.  Try removing that and see if it works.  Other related answers leave it out.  You've verified that path/type are correct?  There's a case where the type doesn't match image/audio/video that you're not handling.

Comment: the type is `xls`. I have already used this code on other app and it worked...but I will try to remove the `application/` part

Comment: The file is `.xls`?  You need to add a case for that in your if/else block to set the correct type then.

Comment: no because if the file is not image or video or audio it will keep type value as `application/xls`

Comment: yeah my fault it isn't `application/xls` but  `application/vnd.ms-excel` but the message is the same

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear, that's what I meant.  There's only one other thing I can think of: do you actually have an app on the phone capable of opening an XLS file?  It's easy to overlook this lol.  If that doesn't work I'm out of suggestions. :(